# Assign a value of an related table into a new table in VS LightSwitch

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using LightSwitch (Learning..) with **VB.Net** and this is my question:
I have some tables called `tOrder` and `tProduct`.
I made a computed property in tOrder that has UNITPRICE and TOTALPRICE.. Total Price was easy to made:

```
Private Sub totalPrice_Compute(ByRef result As Decimal)
    result = quantity * unitPrice
End Sub
```

The problem is with that `unitPrice`. I can not find a way to assign automatically the value of `Price` in `tProduct` according of the user selection. Lets say that in `tProduct` there are 3 products. Product A with a price of 5, Product B with a price of 10 and Product C with a value of 20. I need that in a screen of "New Order", according the selection of the user (If the user wants ProductA/Product B/Product C) that the `UnitPrice` in `tOrder` changes automatically for the user to see the real price of `Price` in `tProduct`.

I tried with:

```
Private Sub unitPrice_Compute(ByRef result As Decimal)
            result = Me.tProduct.price
End Sub
```

But an error appears saying: `NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code`

Also I tried:

```
Private Sub unitPrice_Compute(ByRef result As Decimal)
  If Me.tProduct.nameProduct <> Nothing Then
     result = tProduct.price
  Else
     result = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

But same error..

I don't know how to solve it, or where, when, how.. I am new in LightSwitch and I will be so grateful if you help me..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm assuming you have defined a relationship between the two entities. Could you show a screenshot of your screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is being called before *tProduct* actually has a value, so tyring to reference its *Price* property causes an error.

You were very close with your second piece of code. It just needs to be:

```
Private Sub unitPrice_Compute(ByRef result As Decimal)
  If (Me.tProduct IsNot Nothing) Then
     result = Me.tProduct.price
  Else
     result = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

You should **always** check for *null* (or *Nothing* in VB), in other words that an entity has a value, before using any of its properties. Also you can't use *<>* in a comparison with *Nothing*, you have to use *Is* or *IsNot*.

A simpler alternative would be to write the code like this (although the above version is fine too):

```
Private Sub unitPrice_Compute(ByRef result As Decimal)
  result = If(Me.tProduct Is Nothing, 0, Me.tProduct.price)
End Sub
```